# Concatenating a column with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Would it be possible to update one table column data by concatenating the column data from the other table? Let me explain with simple example,

Table A: studentaccess

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID ║ AccCode  ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║    12  ║ Tom      ║
║    13  ║ Ann      ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Table B : studentdetails

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ID     ║ UserName          ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════╣
║    1   ║ raj_12_kumar      ║
║    2   ║ test_13_test      ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Now I want to split the `UserName` column data and fetch the second token from that and query `studentaccess` table by matching the `UserID` and get the `AccCode` value from it and concatenate the same with second token of the `UserName` column data. Finally I need `studentdetails` table data something like below,

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ID     ║ UserName          ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════╣
║    1   ║ 12_Tom            ║
║    2   ║ 13_Ann            ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

From the below substr query I can get the `UserId` value from the `UserName` column in the `studentdetails` table,

```
select regexp_substr(UserName, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){1}$', 1, 1, null, 1) as userId  from studentdetails
```

Any one help me to concatenate the same with `Acccode` and update the same in `UserName` column?

Comment: You tagged 4 different DB. Which one do you use actually?

Comment: Oracle database

Comment: And you tagged other DBMS systems, but not oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following query, which I have tested and verified on my end.

You can check out the Oracle version at this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd66c/1

**Oracle version**

```
UPDATE studentdetails sd
SET sd.UserName =
  (SELECT  to_char(x.UserID) || '_' || sa.AccCode
   FROM 
     (SELECT  sd1.ID as ID, SUBSTR(sd1.UserName, INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_') + 1, INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_', INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_') + 1) - 1 - INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_')) AS UserID
      FROM studentdetails sd1 
     ) x  INNER JOIN studentaccess sa ON TO_NUMBER(x.UserID) = sa.UserID where sd.ID = x.ID   
  );
```

**SQL Server version**

```
UPDATE studentdetails
SET UserName =
  (SELECT x.UserID + '_' + sa.AccCode
   FROM
     (SELECT SUBSTRING(sd1.UserName, CHARINDEX('_', sd1.UserName) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', sd1.UserName, CHARINDEX('_', sd1.UserName) + 1) - 1 - CHARINDEX('_', sd1.UserName)) AS UserID
      FROM studentdetails sd1
      WHERE sd1.ID = studentdetails.ID) x
   INNER JOIN studentaccess sa ON x.UserID = sa.UserID);
```

**UPDATE 1**

You can use the query below if you want the string UNKNOWN in column UserName of studentdetails table if studentaccess table does not contain the UserID obtained from studentdetails table.

I could not try it out in sqlfiddle since sqlfiddle is not loading up due to some issues. Whenever, it comes back online I will try it out and let you know. In the meantime, you could try this on your end and let me know of any issues.

```
UPDATE studentdetails sd
SET sd.UserName =
  (SELECT  CASE when x.ID is null then 'UNKNOWN' else  to_char(x.UserID) || '_' || sa.AccCode END
   FROM 
     (SELECT  sd1.ID as ID, SUBSTR(sd1.UserName, INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_') + 1, INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_', INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_') + 1) - 1 - INSTR( sd1.UserName,'_')) AS UserID
      FROM studentdetails sd1 
     ) x  RRIGHT OUTER JOIN studentaccess sa ON TO_NUMBER(x.UserID) = sa.UserID where sd.ID = x.ID   
  );
```

Comment: your solution is also working as expected, but I need a bit modification in the query. like if it found matches with the sa.userId then it should updated the concatinated string else it should update with String 'UNKNOWN'. Tried using Case (When/Then) but getting some issues with the same, Is there any alternative way for this?

Comment: @SQLLearner, So, if studentaccess table does not contain the UserID then update to UNKNOWN. Is that correct?

Comment: @SQLLearner, try the query under UPDATE 1 and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE StudentDetails sd
SET UserName = 
( 
    SELECT userid||'_'||AccCode 
    FROM StudentAccess sa 
    WHERE regexp_substr(sd.UserName, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){1}$', 1, 1, null, 1) = sa.userid
);
```

Comment: It is working as expected, need a bit modification in the query. like if it found matches with the sa.userid then it should updated the cncatinated string else it should update with String 'UNKNOWN'.  Tried using Case (When/Then) but getting some issues with the same, Is there any alternative way for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near. You can concatenate other column with userName.

```
regexp_substr(UserName, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){1}$', 1, 1, null, 1) || '_' || acccode
```

Result with your sample data will be like this -

```
    select userid, regexp_substr(UserName, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){1}$', 1, 1, null, 1) || '_' || acccode as username  from 
(
select 1 UserID, 'Tom' AccCode from dual
union
select  1 userid , 'Ann' AccCode from dual) studentaccess,
( select 1 ID, 'raj_12_kumar' username from dual
 union
 select 2 id, 'test_13_test' username from dual) studentdetails
 where studentaccess.userid = studentdetails.ID
```